# “Platform application is disabled” AWS SNS Service

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I'm receiving “Platform application is disabled” from amazon SNS service when trying to publish to ios device.

iOS push certificate is valid for the next year. 
when I get the platformApplicationAttributes object, I see the valid certificate date and "Enabled" = false.

So I then use the setPlatformApplicationAttribute, and set Enabled =true, then send the push. Which succeeds through the API with a valid requestId - but in fact, the device is not receiving the push although push notifications are enabled for this app.

Also, publishing through the sns console directly gave the same error:
**Platform application is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PlatformApplicationDisabled; Request ID: ****)**
Any idea how this could be solved?

Comment: Did you try sending the notification to the device using the AWS console? You can use "Publish to Endpoint" by selecting the token in the application interface.

Comment: Is the app configured and registered with the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) to receive push notifications?

Comment: @ShuchiSethi publishing to specific endpoints wasn't successful as well directly from their console. It gave the same error:
Platform application is disabled (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: PlatformApplicationDisabled; Request ID: ******)

Comment: @ShuchiSethi Is the registration something I can see from the developer account?